# Wordpress - задать условие

Tags: php, wordpress, условия

Есть вывод дочерних рубрик с постами одной указанной рубрики с id 23.
Все работает прекрасно, но нужно задать условие, не выводить рубрики, у которых нету постов. Как можно задать это условие?

```
<?php
$parent_id = 23;

# получаем дочерние рубрики
$sub_cats = get_categories( array(
'child_of' => $parent_id,
'hide_empty' => 0
) );
if( $sub_cats ){
foreach( $sub_cats as $cat ){

    echo '<div class="cat-name-h3" id="cat-'. $cat->cat_ID . '">'. $cat->name .'</div>';

    # получаем записи из рубрики
    $myposts = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'category'    => $cat->cat_ID,
        'orderby'     => 'post_date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
    ) );
    # выводим записи
    global $post;
    foreach($myposts as $post){
        setup_postdata($post);
                get_template_part('loop5'); // для отображения каждой записи берем шаблон loop.php
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем глобальную переменную пост
};?>
```

Comment: 'hide_empty' => 1

Comment: Большое спасибо! Оказалось все очень просто, не знаю, как сам не доглядел))